# cannot update database without error

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

Part 1, the code below is the function from another class.

```
public static void updateData(string SqlCommand)
{
    string strConString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SOConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(strConString);
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(SqlCommand, conn);

    try {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        conn.Close();

    }   
}
```

here is the code to call the function above.

```
protected void ImageButton2_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {

            string ID = txtID.Text;
            string password = txtPassword.Text;
            string name = txtName.Text;
            string position = txtPosition.Text;
            int status = 1;
            string createOn = validate.GetTimestamp(DateTime.Now); ;
            string accessRight;
            if (RadioButton1.Checked)
                accessRight = "Administrator";
            else
                accessRight = "Non-administrator";

            //    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "yourMessage", "alert('" + ID + "ha " + password + "ha " + status + "ha " + accessRight + "ha " + position + "ha " + name + "ha " + createOn + "');", true);

            string type = (String)Session["type"];


            if (type == "update")
                {
                    string sqlcommand = "UPDATE USERMASTER SET USERPOSITION='"+position+"',USERNAME='"+name+"' WHERE (USERID ='"+ID+"')";
                    readdata.updateData(sqlcommand);
                    Response.Redirect("UserView.aspx");
                }
             else {             
                    if (validate.verifyID(ID) == true)
                    {
                        if (validate.verifyLang((String)Session["Lang"]) == true)
                            lblIDError.Text = "User ID already exist！";
                        else
                            lblIDError.Text = "用户账号已存在！";
                    }
                    else{
                        string sqlcommand = "INSERT INTO USERMASTER (USERID,USERPWD,USERNAME,USERPOSITION,USERACCESSRIGHTS,USERSTATUS,CREATEDATE,CREATEUSERID) VALUES ('" + ID + "','" + password + "','" + name + "','" + position + "','" + accessRight + "','" + status + "', TO_DATE('" + createOn + "'),'" + (string)Session["UserID"] + "')";
                        readdata.updateData(sqlcommand);
                        Response.Redirect("UserView.aspx");

                    }
                }
            }
```

part 1 code running well for INSERT, but when come to UPDATE, it doesnt show me error and also doesnt UPDATE the data. anyone know what is wrong with my code?

Comment: I don't know if you need quotes around your id's seeing as they are numerical? also manually inserting primary keys (which I think your userId is but don't know for sure because I don't know what your table is like) is bad practice, you should use an auto increment column instead

Comment: maybe `type != "update"` :)

Comment: what is value of id u are updating for ? do that exist in db?

Comment: What is the error message in your catch? You should log it instead of just closing the connection.

Comment: What are your column types? What is your `sqlcommand` looks like just before you execute it? Debug your code and tell us. And you should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: @SonerGönül both the position and name are nvarchar.

Comment: @FlorinGhita i dont think so.. coz i tried the part of code is running.. just its doesn't update the database

Comment: @JeremyC.even without the  quote also give me the same error... this is one of the method i get from online resources, its doesnt work also

Comment: @utility yeap, coz INSERT there also have position and name.

Comment: @Handsome give us a definition of your table by editing your original question and putting your column definitions there, also try to debug your code and see what query is being sent to the database so we can help you out more specifically and probably find an answer much faster

Comment: place a breaker at update and post the query with question

Comment: @utility i tried to place the wrong query into the sqlcommand but its still can run... what does u mean by post the query with question?

Comment: Just as an FYI: `GUI` should not contain `sql queries`, you should surround your `connections` and `commands` with `using`s, and use `parameters` instead of string concatenation. If you start with this, it will let more room to spot the actual problem

Comment: place a breaker at your query and see whether query is having correct value of id

Comment: @utility sorry i am new,do you mind to share how to do it?

Comment: @SébastienSevrin but the things is the updatedata() function is work perfectly with INSERT statement, its only doesnt work for UPDATE. Herm..

Comment: Having something working on a specific case does not mean it should be done, I was just giving best practices, that should keep you away from side effects like what you are experiencing at the moment

Comment: @SébastienSevrin true, sorry if my word meant anything to you. coz I studied few cases, its work the same way. because I am kinda new to oracle and I do not know what actually is happening..

Comment: In case you don't know how to debug then put the sqlcommand to a Textbox or similar in your UI. Copy the command and use it in your favorite database tool to execute there and see what happens. Try to find a command in that tool that does what you want and then construct that command in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the value used in the update statements where condition is missing the value.You can find using breakers,that might give you some idea about finding the answer,as you dont know that let me post here how to break and find them.

Below are the picture to break and view the query with value.

[image]

[image]